# Who is subscribing to loadCollection$ effect in this @ngrx example?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

I don't understand who is subscribing to the effect `loadCollection$` and how is this observable started in this [@ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/17a1987ee037f7f3d91bbe7df5e1d70e14ca3c77/src/app/effects/collection.ts) example. Can someone explain?

```
@Effect()
  loadCollection$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(collection.ActionTypes.LOAD)
    .startWith(new collection.LoadAction())
    .switchMap(() =>
      this.db.query('books')
        .toArray()
        .map((books: Book[]) => new collection.LoadSuccessAction(books))
        .catch(error => of(new collection.LoadFailAction(error)))
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a self starting observable because of

`ofType(collection.ActionTypes.LOAD)`

The `@ngrx` effects framework subscribe to the `loadCollection$`.